# Nodemon vs Node: Code works in Node but not Nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I have a basic route in my app.js file that is saving a file which was uploaded by the user and then a python script is called. However, the current code works when I execute the app.js file via node (i.e. `node app.js`) but it does not execute when I call `nodemon app.js`. Please see code below:

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const { exec } = require("child_process");

app.post("/modelling", async (req, res) => {
  let allParameters = req.body; 
  await fs.writeFile("./allParams.json", JSON.stringify(data), "utf8");
  exec(
    "python3 path/to/my/main.py",
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.log("inside exec2");
      if (error) {
        console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`stdout:\n${stdout}`);
    }
  );
);
```

Is there a reason that code works in a node environment but not a nodemon environment?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any error while executing the `nodemon app.js` command?

Comment: @PyxlDavon I wish...one of the few times I'm hoping to see errors.  I insert a few console.log statements and I can see the call to exec is never being executed. It's like nodemon is exiting the function prior to calling exec.